# How do Facebook comment plugins in other websites know my Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Some websites embed Facebook plugins, e.g., comment with Facebook, Facebook messenger live chat, etc.

The first time I visit one of those sites, they already know my currently logged in Facebook account.

How is that possible technically?

Answer (score 0):

Because Facebook knows your browser. When you logged in, it almost certainly set cookies, but it can identify your browser in other ways, like your IP address, installed add-ins, et cetera and so on.

Since the plugins are also served from Facebook's domain(s), it can "see" your browser when you visit other sites, so it knows it's you.

Comment: Other websites cant access fb cookie or localstorage, right? I can make comments/likes in those websites. So they can do that too, without my consent?

Comment: You consent when you log into Facebook. I'm sure it's all there in their Privacy Policy. Other sites can't access the data, but Facebook can give it to them.